# How to pass multiple parameters to R.cond ramda function?

Tags: javascript, parameters, ramda.js

Here is the ramda function that accept a string parameter

```
const decodeBarcode => R.cond([
  [x => R.equals(x.length, 12), decodeUPACBarcode],
  [x => R.equals(x.length, 13), decode13DigitBarcode],
  [x => R.gt(x.length, 20), decodeLengthGT20Barcode],
  [R.T, R.identity],
]);
```

How to pass another parameter to improve condition?

another parameter barcodeType to be included

```
if (barcode.length > 20 or barcodeType = "DATAMATRIX")
```

Tried the below, not working !!

```
 const decodeBarcode = (barcode, barcodeType) => R.cond([
      [x => R.equals(x.length, 12), decodeUPACBarcode],
      [x => R.equals(x.length, 13), decode13DigitBarcode],
      [x => R.or(R.propEq('DATAMATRIX', barcodeType), R.gt(x.length, 20)), decodeLengthGT20Barcode],
      [R.T, R.identity],
    ])(barcode);
```

[RamdaJS REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20decodeLength13Barcode%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%27Its%2013%20digit%20barcode%27%29%0A%29%0A%0Avar%20decodeLengthGT20Barcode%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%27Its%20%3E%2020%20digit%20barcode%27%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20decodeBarcode%20%3D%20%28barcode%2C%20barcodeType%29%20%3D%3E%20R.cond%28%5B%0A%20%20%5Bx%20%3D%3E%20R.equals%28x.length%2C%2013%29%2C%20decodeLength13Barcode%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5Bx%20%3D%3E%20R.either%28R.propEq%28%27DATAMATRIX%27%2C%20barcodeType%29%2C%20R.gt%28x.length%2C%2020%29%29%2C%20decodeLengthGT20Barcode%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5BR.T%2C%20R.identity%5D%2C%0A%5D%29%28barcode%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28decodeBarcode%28%270272889010009%27%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28decodeBarcode%28%2702728890100099898989%27%29%29%3B%0A)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `R.anyPass` to run a list of predicates against a value, and return `true` is any of the predicate returns `true`:

```js
const { cond, propEq, anyPass, propSatisfies, lte, T, identity } = R

const decodeLength13Barcode = () => console.log('Its 13 digit barcode')
const decodeLengthGT20Barcode = () => console.log('Its > 20 digit barcode')

const decodeBarcode = (barcode, barcodeType) => cond([
  [propEq('length', 13), decodeLength13Barcode],
  [anyPass([
    propEq('DATAMATRIX', barcodeType),
    propSatisfies(lte(20), 'length')
  ]), decodeLengthGT20Barcode],
  [T, identity],
])(barcode);

console.log(decodeBarcode('0272889010009'));
console.log(decodeBarcode('02728890100099898989'));
console.log(decodeBarcode({ DATAMATRIX: '20d' }, '20d'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Since `R.cond` passes all parameters to the predicates, you can remove the arrow function (point-free). However, you pass `bardcode, barcodeType`, while `R. propEq`  expects `barcodeType, barcode`, so you'll need to flip it after stating the property (`DATAMATRIX`):

```js
const { cond, propEq, anyPass, flip, propSatisfies, lte, T, identity } = R

const decodeLength13Barcode = () => console.log('Its 13 digit barcode')
const decodeLengthGT20Barcode = () => console.log('Its > 20 digit barcode')

const decodeBarcode = cond([
  [propEq('length', 13), decodeLength13Barcode],
  [anyPass([
    flip(propEq('DATAMATRIX')),
    propSatisfies(lte(20), 'length')
  ]), decodeLengthGT20Barcode],
  [T, identity],
]);

console.log(decodeBarcode('0272889010009'));
console.log(decodeBarcode('02728890100099898989'));
console.log(decodeBarcode({ DATAMATRIX: '20d' }, '20d'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: both parameters should be string, like decodeBarcode("02728890100099898989", "DATAMATRIX");

Comment: It's a string with the property `"DATAMATRIX"`?

Comment: Interesting.  But see my answer for what I think is a more likely interpretation of the requirements.

Comment: Not sure - he's using `R.propEq('DATAMATRIX', barcodeType)`. if you're right it should have been `R.eq`.

Comment: Not sure either.  That `propEq` is only in the broken code, and the title as well as text make me think it's about an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```js
const decodeBarcode = cond ([
  [propEq ('length', 12), decodeUPACBarcode],
  [propEq ('length', 13), decode13DigitBarcode],
  [(barcode, barcodeType) => barcode.length > 20 || barcodeType == "DATAMATRIX" , decodeLengthGT20Barcode],
  [T, identity],
]);

const testCases = [
  ['123456789012', 'TYPEA'], 
  ['1234567890123'], 
  ['123456789012345678901'],
  ['12345678901234567', 'DATAMATRIX'],
  ['12345678901324567']
]

testCases .forEach (xs => console .log (
  `decodeBarcode ('${xs .join(`', '`)}')\n//==> ${decodeBarcode (...xs)}`
))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> 
const {cond, propEq, T, identity} = R
const decodeUPACBarcode = (barcode, type = '') => `calling decodeUPACBarcode('${barcode}', '${type}')`
const decode13DigitBarcode = (barcode, type = '') => `calling decode13DigitBarcode('${barcode}', '${type}')`
const decodeLengthGT20Barcode = (barcode, type = '') => `calling decodeLengthGT20Barcode('${barcode}', '${type}')`
</script>
```

While we always have a way to make a function point-free, and it was worth doing for the first two conditions, the third one is going to be ugly enough that I wouldn't do it except as academic exercise.  It might end up being something like this:

```js
pipe (
  unapply (zipWith (call) ([propSatisfies (gt (__, 20), 'length'), equals ('DATAMATRIX')])),
  apply (or)
)
```

and that is *much* less readable than the arrow function currently used.